# 'Need at least one array to concatenate' error in mmsegmentation with custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am trying to train a segmentation model with a custom dataset via mmsegmentation. However, after making the necessary alterations to the config file, I keep getting this error:

*ValueError: class `IterBasedTrainLoop` in mmengine/runner/loops.py: class `BaseSegDataset` in mmseg/datasets/basesegdataset.py: need at least one array to concatenate*

From what I've gathered based on online searches, it seems to be related to the customization of the config file. More specifically, the customization of the class names.

Has anyone bumped into a similar issue?

Here's the config file. It's big.

```
_base_ = [
    '../_base_/models/setr_mla.py', '../_base_/datasets/ade20k.py',
    '../_base_/default_runtime.py', '../_base_/schedules/schedule_160k.py'
]

crop_size = (512, 512)
data_preprocessor = dict(size=crop_size)
norm_cfg = dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True)

num_classes=1

metainfo = dict(classes = ('class_name',),
                palette = [(220, 20, 60),])

dataset_type = 'BaseSegDataset'
data_root = 'path_to_dataset_root_folder'
img_suffix='.png'
seg_map_suffix='.png'

pre_trained_weights_path = 'path_to_weights/weights.pth'

reduce_zero_label = True

model = dict(
    data_preprocessor=data_preprocessor,
    pretrained=None,
    backbone=dict(
        img_size=(512, 512),
        drop_rate=0.,
        init_cfg=dict(
            type='Pretrained', checkpoint=pre_trained_weights_path)),
    decode_head=dict(num_classes=num_classes),
    auxiliary_head=[
        dict(
            type='FCNHead',
            in_channels=256,
            channels=256,
            in_index=0,
            dropout_ratio=0,
            norm_cfg=norm_cfg,
            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),
            num_convs=0,
            kernel_size=1,
            concat_input=False,
            num_classes=num_classes,
            align_corners=False,
            loss_decode=dict(
                type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=0.4)),
        dict(
            type='FCNHead',
            in_channels=256,
            channels=256,
            in_index=1,
            dropout_ratio=0,
            norm_cfg=norm_cfg,
            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),
            num_convs=0,
            kernel_size=1,
            concat_input=False,
            num_classes=num_classes,
            align_corners=False,
            loss_decode=dict(
                type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=0.4)),
        dict(
            type='FCNHead',
            in_channels=256,
            channels=256,
            in_index=2,
            dropout_ratio=0,
            norm_cfg=norm_cfg,
            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),
            num_convs=0,
            kernel_size=1,
            concat_input=False,
            num_classes=num_classes,
            align_corners=False,
            loss_decode=dict(
                type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=0.4)),
        dict(
            type='FCNHead',
            in_channels=256,
            channels=256,
            in_index=3,
            dropout_ratio=0,
            norm_cfg=norm_cfg,
            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),
            num_convs=0,
            kernel_size=1,
            concat_input=False,
            num_classes=num_classes,
            align_corners=False,
            loss_decode=dict(
                type='CrossEntropyLoss', use_sigmoid=False, loss_weight=0.4)),
    ],
    test_cfg=dict(mode='slide', crop_size=(512, 512), stride=(341, 341)),
)

optimizer = dict(lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.0)
optim_wrapper = dict(
    type='OptimWrapper',
    optimizer=optimizer,
    paramwise_cfg=dict(custom_keys={'head': dict(lr_mult=10.)}))

train_dataloader = dict(
    batch_size=8,
    num_workers=8,
    persistent_workers=True,
    sampler=dict(type='InfiniteSampler', shuffle=True),
    dataset=dict(
        type=dataset_type,
        data_root=data_root,
        metainfo=metainfo,
        data_prefix=dict(
            img_path='images/training', 
            seg_map_path='annotations/training'),
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(type='LoadAnnotations', reduce_zero_label=True),
            dict(
                type='RandomResize',
                scale=(2048, 512),
                ratio_range=(0.5, 2.0),
                keep_ratio=True),
            dict(type='RandomCrop', crop_size=(512, 512), cat_max_ratio=0.75),
            dict(type='RandomFlip', prob=0.5),
            dict(type='PhotoMetricDistortion'),
            dict(type='PackSegInputs')
        ]))

val_dataloader = dict(
    batch_size=8,
    num_workers=8,
    persistent_workers=True,
    sampler=dict(type='DefaultSampler', shuffle=False),
    dataset=dict(
        type=dataset_type,
        data_root=data_root,
        metainfo=metainfo,
        data_prefix=dict(
            img_path='images/validation',
            seg_map_path='annotations/validation'),
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(type='Resize', scale=(2048, 512), keep_ratio=True),
            dict(type='LoadAnnotations', reduce_zero_label=True),
            dict(type='PackSegInputs')
        ]))

test_dataloader = dict(
    batch_size=8,
    num_workers=8,
    persistent_workers=True,
    sampler=dict(type='DefaultSampler', shuffle=False),
    dataset=dict(
        type=dataset_type,
        data_root=data_root,
        metainfo=metainfo,
        data_prefix=dict(
            img_path='images/test',
            seg_map_path='annotations/test'),
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(type='Resize', scale=(2048, 512), keep_ratio=True),
            dict(type='LoadAnnotations', reduce_zero_label=True),
            dict(type='PackSegInputs')
        ]))
```

Here's the full error log, in case it's necessary.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 122, in build_from_cfg
    obj = obj_cls(**args)  # type: ignore
  File "/mmsegmentation/mmseg/datasets/basesegdataset.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.full_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/dataset/base_dataset.py", line 310, in full_init
    self.data_bytes, self.data_address = self._serialize_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/dataset/base_dataset.py", line 772, in _serialize_data
    data_bytes = np.concatenate(data_list)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 122, in build_from_cfg
    obj = obj_cls(**args)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 219, in __init__
    super().__init__(runner, dataloader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/base_loop.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.dataloader = runner.build_dataloader(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1346, in build_dataloader
    dataset = DATASETS.build(dataset_cfg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/registry.py", line 548, in build
    return self.build_func(cfg, *args, **kwargs, registry=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 144, in build_from_cfg
    raise type(e)(
ValueError: class `BaseSegDataset` in mmseg/datasets/basesegdataset.py: need at least one array to concatenate

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mmsegmentation/tools/train.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mmsegmentation/tools/train.py", line 100, in main
    runner.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1687, in train
    self._train_loop = self.build_train_loop(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1479, in build_train_loop
    loop = LOOPS.build(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/registry.py", line 548, in build
    return self.build_func(cfg, *args, **kwargs, registry=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mmengine/registry/build_functions.py", line 144, in build_from_cfg
    raise type(e)(
ValueError: class `IterBasedTrainLoop` in mmengine/runner/loops.py: class `BaseSegDataset` in mmseg/datasets/basesegdataset.py: need at least one array to concatenate
srun: error: gr13b04n04: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

Comment: that's a lot of `dict()` calls. python has dict literals but they're not as sexy as javascript object literals. the python dict literal requires the keys to be proper strings, not like `dict()` with keyword arguments, where you can write them as identifiers.

Comment: Yep, but that's the way this library works, apparently. Most of that config file was automatically generated by it.